# Jquery Open And close with the same button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button that opens a small window to show extra information.
At the moment it only opens and I have to click the close button to close it, I really don't want this close button but I would like to be able to open and close it with the same button.

```
 $(function() {
    //----- OPEN
    $('[data-popup-open]').on('click', function(e)  {
        var targeted_popup_class = jQuery(this).attr('data-popup-open');
        $('[data-popup="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]').fadeIn(350);

        e.preventDefault();
    });

    //----- CLOSE
    $('[data-popup-close]').on('click', function(e)  {
        var targeted_popup_class = jQuery(this).attr('data-popup-close');
        $('[data-popup="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]').fadeOut(350);

        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Can anyone help me in this?

Comment: its because the click events are bound to items that exist at that time, you should use event delegation.

Comment: perhaps you should use `.toggle` instead.

Comment: @DanielA.White The hover overs are created in a for loop inside of a calendar, they may or may not be created depending on how many events are on that day so i needs it to bound to items.

Comment: @DanielA.White i wouldn't know how to include a toggle into it in the state it is :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `fadeToggle()` `jQuery` function.

```
$('button').on('click', function(e)  {
    var targeted_popup_class = jQuery(this).attr('data-popup-open');
    $('[data-popup="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]').fadeToggle(350);

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Beautiful, you got it! I will put solved as soon as i can ~5min,

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
$('[data-popup-open-close]').on('click', function(e)  {
      if(!$(this).hasClass("opened")){
        //code for open
        $(this).addClass("opened")
      }else{
        //code for close
        $(this).removeClass("opened")
      }  
    });
```

Comment: This seems to me the better solution because it decouples the open / close logic from the style (that can be setted in CSS)

Answer (score 0):

You only need to find out, when you click, if the layer is open or close and react of consequence.

I have used `$(..).is(':visible')` for an example, but you have to find out the best function for your scenario.

Something like..

```
 $(function() {

    //----- OPEN and CLOSE
    $('[data-popup-close]').on('click', function(e)  {
        var targeted_popup_class = jQuery(this).attr('data-popup-close');

        // for example
        var isOpen = $('[data-popup="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]').is(':vivible'); 

        if (isOpen) {
            $('[data-popup="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]').fadeOut(350);
        } else {
            $('[data-popup="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]').fadeIn(350);
        }


        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart of `fadeToggle()` method, you can know if a box is visible or not:

```
$('button').on('click', function(e)  {
    var targeted_popup_class = jQuery(this).attr('data-popup-open');
    if($('[data-popup="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]').is(':visible')) {
         //close it!
    } else {
         // open it!
    }

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope it should be work for you.

```
$(function() {
    $('[data-popup-open]').on('click', function(e)  {
        if($(this).hasClass('data-popup-open'))
        {
            $('[data-popup="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]').fadeOut(350);
        }
        else if($(this).hasClass('data-popup-close'))
        {
            $('[data-popup="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]').fadeIn(350);
        }
        $(this).toggleClass('data-popup-open')
        $(this).toggleClass('data-popup-close')
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```